# Changing NBT of an item in a container in 1.17

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I'm looking to add nbt to an item that's inside a dropper. For example: there's a wooden sword in the middle slot. First you add +10 Damage and +1 Attack speed to it. Then you add Fire Aspect II on it. And last you add a tag "Level3" and lore saying "Wildfire" to it.

I haven't done this before so I'm going to need a lot of explanation.

I had a question a lot like this one, but it's not for 1.17 and I can't get it to work.

Comment: What do you mean by "a level 3 tag"? Do you mean a custom NBT tag that can be detected later?

Comment: Yeah, just a custom tag to check for later. I'm trying to make weapons that can be upgraded 3 times and I need to keep track of the level.
Since each upgrade can be different I can't just make a complete version with every combination because that would soon reach over thousands in number.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This would require a lot of NBT modification. Let's look at what the completed NBT of your item should look like:

```
{
  AttributeModifiers: [
    {
      AttributeName: "generic.attack_damage",
      Slot: "mainhand",
      Operation: 0,
      Amount: 10.0d,
      UUID: [I;382757,9285892,28488284,19948385]
    },
    {
      AttributeName: "generic.attack_damage",
      Slot: "mainhand",
      Operation: 0,
      Amount: 10.0d,
      UUID: [I;382757,9285892,28488284,19948387]
    }
  ],
  Enchantments: [
    {id: "minecraft:fire_aspect", lvl: 2}
  ],
  display: {
    Lore: ['"Wildfire"']
  },
  Level3: 1b
}
```

You can modify the data of an item in the dropper using the following command:

```
data modify block ~ ~ ~ Items[{Slot:4b}].tag merge value …
```

From there, insert the NBT data I placed above.

Comment: Thank you! This helps, only one thing I hoped I could do is add lore rather than replace the already existing one. But other than that it works exactly as I hoped.

Comment: @WickedGrinn I'm not sure if that's even possible. You might be able to combine the lists by doing some other kind of more complicated thing and then set the new list as the lore, but I don't know too much about that. Just an idea

Comment: @WickedGrinn Oh, you can do that, just leave the `Lore` out of the first command, then use a separate command to add the lore text.

Comment: @Penguin No, it's possible. Hint: `data modify storage namespace:test MyList append value "second list item"`

Comment: just an addition, you can change the nbt selector from Items[{Slot:4b}] to anything more specific. If you want to select a wooden sword, then you can do Items[{id:"minecraft:wooden_sword"}] or any other tag that describes the item you want to target